# MAC OS Sierra - Run app at startup?

Tags: macos, plist, startup, macos-sierra, launchd

I am trying to set an application (*.app) to run at startup in MAC OS Sierra. I know that a plist has to be added to the following folder,

> /Library/LaunchAgents

I created a plist with the code below. It needs to run as admin at startup every time MAC OS is loaded. But it is not working. The app does not start at startup. How to make the app work at startup?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myapp.startup</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>        
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>${installdir}/startup.stdout</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>${installdir}/startup.stderr</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>admin</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>admin</string>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: You need to register the file with launchd using launchctl. You'll probably find more help on the dedicated Apple Stack Exchange site, e.g. [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308421) has a quick guide.

Comment: You may also want to create this as a LaunchDaemon. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290945/what-are-the-differences-between-launchagents-and-launchdaemons?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)